# How to include line breaks in textarea tag in create post in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have the following code and I just noticed when I post a post with two paragraphs the line break break between the paragraphs is ignored. The output is one long paragraph without any line break. Is there a way to fix that.

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <!-- Body-->
        <label for="body"><span>Body</span></label>
        <textarea id="body" name="body">{{ old('body') }}</textarea>
        @error('body')
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        @enderror
        <!-- Button -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply a CSS style to your text area to preserve the line breaks:

```html
<textarea id="body" name="body" class='preserveLines'>{{ old('body') }}</textarea>
```

```css
.preserveLines {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, your view on this and XSS attacks?

Comment: Shouldn’t be an issue as you are escaping the output using the Laravel blade double brackets syntax already (this is built in)

Answer (score 4):

Use PHP's [`nl2br()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) in combination with [outputting HTML in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data):

```html
<textarea id="body" name="body">{!! nl2br(old('body')) !!}</textarea>
```

This will display the `old('body')` input, keeping HTML formatting and spaces intact.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. When I click submit, the post is added to the database and when I render from the from the database that's where I get one long paragraph regardless of how many paragraphs I typed  in the form!

Comment: Same idea; `\n` (or a carriage-return, newline) is saved to the database, and unless you wrap it in `nl2br()`, it won't render as new line/line break when displayed in HTML. So instead of wrapping `old('body')`, you'd wrap `$post->body`, so `{!! nl2br($post->body) !!}`

Comment: Thanks, that works and two questions though... 1. Are XSS attacks taken care of in this case. And why wouldn't this work ```{!! $post->body !!}```?

Comment: Hmm yeah, XSS attacks might be a problem if they add a `<script>` to their input; but not if you're rendering that into a `<textarea>`. Perhaps the answer below is better if that's a concern, as `{{ }}` isn't vulnerable to XSS, while `{!! !!}` is. Also, `{!! $post->body !!}` would work fine on it's own, but simply wouldn't do much. `{!! !!}` is used to transform stuff like `<br/>`, `<p>`, `<span>`, etc. into actual HTML elements, as opposed to just outputting them.

Comment: You could escape the string by yourself: `{!! nl2br(htmlspecialchars($post->body, ENT_QUOTES)) !!}`